# "Pin" Controls Together in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have two controls: a button and a textbox, for example.  If the textbox position moves, I'd like the button position to move as well.  If possible, I'd like it to be instantaneous (otherwise I would just use a very fast timer).  Using a timer has worked so far, but I can drag the text box around, and when I do, the button lags behind.  Is there any way to do it in a less laggy way?

Comment: Your question title says "in Visual Studio" so it's really not clear to me whether you're trying to accomplish this in the designer or at run-time. If it's at run-time, is it the user that is moving the button or are you talking about during the resize of the window?

Comment: I'm talking about at runtime.  The user can move the textbox themself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook your code up to the `Move` or the `LocationChanged` events for the textbox.